# addEventListener not working after appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, addeventlistener

I have one ul, and add dynamically an option element and inside that option one anchor element.

The problem begins when I add an event on the anchor! Not working!

HTML:

```
<ul></ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
var option = document.createElement('option');
var a = document.createElement('a');

a.innerHTML = "click me";

a.addEventListener('click',function(){
   alert('event successful!');
});

option.appendChild(a);

ul.appendChild(option);
```

See in JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/63h8kqp1/

Comment: I tried the jsfiddle link. The example worked for me -> on click a alert appeared.

Comment: `a` should not be `child` of `option`

Comment: in google chrome not working..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add anchor "a" element inside "option", look how this works:

```js
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
var li = document.createElement('li');
li.innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:alert(\"clicked\")'>click me</a>";
ul.appendChild(li);
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: why insert an option insed ul, the logic will be insert li inside. check the edited answer

Comment: Ohh, truth.. I mistook before doing with select .. kakaka